Delete subfolders that start with a specific character AND are more than # days old - powershell
We have a very manual process here where when servers start filling up disk space, we go the user profiles in C:\Users and delete folders that are over 24 hours old that begin with "Z" as our offshore resources don't tend to follow the logoff process and leave old profiles in place.
I'm working on a PS script to remove and folders that begin with Z from the C:\Users folder but I am finding it goes after anything with Z in it in other subfolders of other users.
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Name -ilike "z*"} | Remove-Item -Force


Remove the -Recurse

Do not -Recurse. Specify that you only want to work on directories using the -Directory switch.
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\' -Directory -Filter 'Z*' |
    Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddHours(-24) } |
    Remove-Item -Recurse -Force

If you are on the older Windows PowerShell instead of the current PowerShell Core, then it may not have the -Directory switch.
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\' -Filter 'Z*' |
    Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -and ($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddHours(-24)) } |
    Remove-Item -Recurse -Force

Get current on PowerShell for Linux, Mac, and Windows at https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell.

Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\z*' -Directory is simpler. Not better, just simpler in my opinion. Solid answer though, that should do everything the OP wanted.
